# How to find one of many selectors that contain another nested selector

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-each

I have a web page and there is a list with multiple elements:

**First type of element:**

```
<li class="comp-data-text"> </li>
    <span class="imstuck" data-bind="text"> Something </span>
```

**Second type of element:**

```
<li class="comp-data-text"> </li>
```

As you can see the second one does not contain the "imstuck" class as well as the "Something" text.
(this is an example, in real case the second line of code is nested deeper)

I want to find out which element does or does not contain this line of code. Based on the cypress documentation and a few existing topics I tried:

```
cy.get(...).each(($item) => {
    if ($item.has('span.imstuck')) {
        cy.wrap($item).find('.imstuck').should('contain', 'Something')
    }
})
```

The Cypress GUI runs the code related to if statement even if the element doesn't contain an 'imstuck' class.

```
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: .imstuck, but never found it.
 Queried from element: <li.comp-data-text>
```

I also found another way but it also  works like the previous example:

```
cy.get(...).each(($item) => {
    if ($item.hasClass('.imstuck')) {
        cy.wrap($item).find('.imstuck').should('contain', 'Something')
    }
})
```

**Expected result:**
If the particular element does not contain an '.imstuck' class the if statement won't run the third line of code.

**Actual results**
Error pops up because each time cypress run third line of code even if a particular element doesn't contain 'imstuck' class and when cypress tries to find class 'imstuck' from third line, cypress spits off an error.

Comment: Do you know the order of elements that will contain the child element?

Comment: No, it can be on 1st or 9th place, the order is totally random so I need something that handle each case.

Comment: I should have asked this as well, do you know the amount of elements that will and will not contain the child element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.length` to your if statement

```js
cy.get('li').each(($li) => {
  if ($li.has('span.imstuck').length) {
    cy.wrap($item).find('.imstuck').should('contain', 'Something')
  }
})
```

But may be better to move `'span.imstuck'` up a level. This way you are only getting  those element with the span.

```js
cy.get('li span.imstuck').each(($span) => {
  cy.wrap($span).should('contain', 'Something')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Fody answear I found a little bit simplest way:

```
cy.get('li').each(($li) => {
  if ($li.find('span.imstuck').length) {
    cy.wrap($item).should('contain', 'Something')
  }
})
```

I replace .has() on .find() and then rid off .find() on the next line. It works well too.